# Can't Connect to MySQL Server on IPAddress (10061)

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to connect to a remote MySQL database and have created the following connection code:

```
<?php
/* Set Variables */
$host="myipaddress";
$db="mydbname"; 
$username="dbuser";
$pass="mypass";

/* Attempt to connect */
$mysqli=new mysqli($host,$username,$pass,$db);
if (mysqli_connect_error()){
die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
. mysqli_connect_error());
echo 'Success... ' . $mysqli->host_info . "\n";

$mysqli->close();

}
?>
```

For security reasons, I've not provided the actual variable values.  When I run this on my development system, I receive

```
Connect Error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'myipaddress' (10061)
```

My PHP is a bit rusty, can someone identify where my code is faulty?  Note that dbuser has select, insert and update privileges on the database name set as the variable.

Thanks,
Sid

**Edit**
I made changes to my.cnf and restarted mysql.  I now receive access denied for user 'dbuser'@'mycurrenthostname' (using password YES).  When I use mysql -u dbuser -p from command line, I can login.  I granted insert, update and select to dbuser with host '%' so that dbuser could connect from anywhere.

I've read the MySQL Reference guide about this error, but am still stuck.  Is there a problem with my code, now that my.cnf has been fixed?

Comment: are you sure permissions are setup that allow you to connect?

Comment: Yes, I granted permissions to dbuser and did a flush privileges afterwards.

Comment: my.cnf contains:
#skip-networking
#enable-named-pipes
skip-innodb
max-connections=30
bind-address=127.0.0.1

Comment: `bind-address` should be set to the IP address of the network interface to which you are connecting.  For example, if your MySQL server has a single network interface card (NIC), with an IP address of 192.168.1.200, then `bind-address` should be set to 192.168.1.200. You might also want to check if the server is receiving packets on the MySQL port. On Linux, for example, you could run: `tcpdump port 3306`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check that your firewall is allowing connections through on port 3306.

Check the MySQL configuration parameter `bind-address` in `my.cnf` to ensure that it is allowing remote connections.

There's information and troubleshooting tips here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

Comment: Thanks for the link.  mysqld is running, but cannot execute the first few mysqladmin commands in that article.  Both mysqladmin variables and mysqladmin version return Access denied for user root@localhost using password NO.  Where would the my.cnf file be located and how should I modify bind-address ?  Thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

According to the MySql documentation , The error (2003) Can't connect to MySQL server on 'server' (10061) indicates that the network connection has been refused. You should check that there is a MySQL server running, that it has network connections enabled, and that the network port you specified is the one configured on the server.

I'm not familiar with php , but the problem might not be in your code.

Comment: This error also can appears on Windows if you don't have privileges to create or access to the innoDb data files.

Answer (score 4):

If your getting the above error even after putting the Mysql port 3306 open access,

Just change bind address of mysql file my.cnf which is located at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` 
Update the bind address as given below
`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

This will allow access to all ips remotely 
On AWS ec2 it is working.