# trying to access to mysql remotely

Tags: mysql, host

Im trying to gain access to a mysql database hosted by one site from another website.

In short I am in the middle of transferring from one host to another of my website.
I have imported my database from host A to host B, and also uploaded my website.
Host B is now up and running but I want to keep Host A going for a while until people move over to the new host.

So I want host A to use the db on host B.

I have turned on remote mysql on host B and added the shared ip address of my website of host a. This I believe should allow host a to connect to the db on host B.

I have changed the connection details in my php script to the user,db,password details of the db on host b.

But i'm getting a connection error of cannot connect to db.

I have added my home ip address, created an odbc connection on my pc and used access to connect to the db on host b, with success so I know that host is accepting connections remotely.

I have also tried adding the web address of the my site on host A to the remote mysql, and tried using a open wildcard of '%' hoping that would let any remote connection, but still no look.

Is it possible that host a has blocks on connecting to external mysql databases or am i missing something simple?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using a php script on host A get the site http://checkip.dyndns.com/ and see what IP your host uses to connect to external sources that's the IP you need to white-list to use your MySQL on host B. Does host B use cPanel or some other control panel? if so I doubt they have remote connection blocked but you should ask to make it clear.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Both hosts use cpanel. host a is a free host so is limited, whilst host b the one with the db on is a paid host so has the features such as remote access for mysql. Can you explain the php coding to use checkip.dyndns.com

Comment: are you using the same user when connecting from home and from host a?

Comment: yes am using the same user name as created when setup db on host b. i've just created a script and uploaded it to host a to find the ip address it is using, unfortunately its using the one i've already whitelisted on host a.

Comment: is the user on your php at host A the new user from host b? just to double check.

Comment: yes. If it was a user access problem wouldnt it come up with a access error rather than a connection error?

Comment: @user2391089 I believe it would be the same error something like `users@ip cannot access database blah on ...` have you also changed the database name as it probably changed when you made the new user etc. **If possible post the exact error message you get.**

Comment: have changed the script to match the one i'm using locally and the one thats working on host b, except the host address. the error i'm getting is "Could not connect: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'ip ddress' (4)" where ip address is the ip addess of my host b

Answer (score 0):

Check that your firewall is allowing connections through on port 3306.

Check the MySQL configuration parameter bind-address in my.cnf to ensure that it is allowing remote connections.

There's information and troubleshooting tips here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

I hope this post helps you to debug this issue 
[Can't Connect to MySQL Server on IPAddress (10061)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518845/cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-ipaddress-10061)